# Getting scenario and steps undefined in cucumber with java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, cucumber

I have been battling with this since 2 days. My test is shown passed but the test is not running in cucumber+java for Selenium webdriver test. In the console I am getting following message

```
1 Scenarios (1 undefined)
4 Steps (4 undefined)
0m0.000s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("^User navigate to shopping page$")
public void user_navigate_to_shopping_page() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^user enters data$")
public void user_enters_data() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@When("^clicks on search button$")
public void clicks_on_search_button() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}

@Then("^product should be displayed$")
public void product_should_be_displayed() throws Throwable {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new PendingException();
}
```

I have written following runner class

```
package stepDefinition;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;


@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        monochrome=true,
        features = "src/main/resources/feature",
    glue="src/test/java/stepDefinition",
    tags={"@tag2"},
    dryRun = false)
public class TestRunner {   
}
```

I will also attach the screenshot of directory structure of the project

and the feature file is

```
[![Feature: Checking Functionality
This is a demo test

@tag2
Scenario: Test Login
    Given User navigate to shopping page
    When user enters data
    And clicks on search button
    Then product should be displayed
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to move feautures under /test branch?. Also in intelliJ you can configure module settings and mark test and code folders, is there something similiar in Eclipse?

Comment: I tried moving features under test but no avail :( I am not sure about your second question

Answer (score 5):

The way you have given the value of glue is incorrect. You have to give in java package format. Try `glue = "stepDefinition"` instead.

If you had a package inside your current **stepDefinition** package lets say **steps** which has the code. Then glue becomes `"stepDefinition.steps"`

You should move your features to the test\resources folder.

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue and I tried the fixes provided in the comments along with the above fix there is one more area to look at which is step definiton class.
while looking at my step definition I observed that there are extra spaces after the ^ symbol .I removed the spaces and the test was successfull.

Below was my code when I got the issue .I removed the space after the cap (^) symbol

`@Given("^ I open (.*)$")`

Comment: Very good, it was my problem! Hard to find a tutorial where they say it has to be exactly the same in both places.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to solve a hard problem. That is, you are trying to fix something that never worked.

My approach would be to start with something that worked and then transform that working solution until it supports your use case. I would do that in very small steps if I am unsure about what to do.

A working starting point is the Java skeleton provided by the Cucumber team. Clone/download it can be found here: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: I am able to execute the Feature file successfully but not Runner file that's where I am stuck presently

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check your package created. Make sure you create a different package for each class, test runner class, step definition class and your feature.

I run into a similar problem while trying to have a universal relationship with my packages e.g (comCucumber.feature, comCucumber.step and comCucumber.runner).

Trust this would helpful.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If don't work putting steps in configuration, swithng off Cucumber plugin, try this.
For Maven Project or Gradle:
Right click mouse on pom.xml and choose Rebuild Module or Build Module or press ctlr-shift-F9
For me works good!

For Gradle click on turtle:)

Answer (score -2):

Hi Keep stepdefinition class and test runner class in one package

Comment: This way you can see it running for the first time.. when nothing works this works.. that glue thing is way to difficult to manage