# Cucumber 6.8.1 Undefined scenarios with IntelliJ

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, cucumber, gherkin

I have gone thru numerous solutions here but non of them worked for me. I have set up a simple Cucumber project but when running .feature Scenario I am getting Undefined scenarios error
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saqwX.png)

This is my folder structure created accordingly with official jetbrains recommendation https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/cucumber-support.html

[My project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hLohG.png)

And here .feature amd steps files:
[.feature and steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZQL8.png)

This set up super easy, there is no errors in .feature and steps files(both are seeing eachother) so I guessing maybe something wrong with IntelliJ itself. I will appreciate any help and suggestions!

**!! Update !!**

I found a solution, for some reason only precise folder structure allowed me to run tests, the addition of src/test helped

Comment: Is project sample available?

Comment: Check also this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212449/getting-scenario-and-steps-undefined-in-cucumber-with-java