# unable to run feature file in IntelliJ - Undefined scenarios

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cucumber

I tried to run feature file by right click - run at IntelliJ editor but terminal displayed follows:

this is the configuration by default. is this correct?

please help as I am not sure what should be setup manually over here..

[image]

this is partial log copied from terminal:

```
Undefined scenarios:
C:/Users/tester/Dropbox/My PC (LAPTOP-1UVHO2K0)/Downloads/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master2/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master/src/test/resources/features/creating_todos/adding_new_todos.feature:9 # User should be assisted when adding todo items for the first time
C:/Users/tester/Dropbox/My PC (LAPTOP-1UVHO2K0)/Downloads/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master2/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master/src/test/resources/features/creating_todos/adding_new_todos.feature:13 # Adding a single todo item
C:/Users/tester/Dropbox/My PC (LAPTOP-1UVHO2K0)/Downloads/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master2/bdd-test-automation-workshop-master/src/test/resources/features/creating_todos/adding_new_todos.feature:20 # Adding todo items to an existing list

3 Scenarios (3 undefined)
10 Steps (10 undefined)
0m1.042s


You can implement missing steps with the snippets below:

@Given("{actor}")
public void (Actor actor) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@Then("{actor}")
public void (Actor actor) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new cucumber.api.PendingException();
}

@When("{actor}")
public void (Actor actor) {
}

@Then("{actor}")
public void (Actor actor, io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) {

}

@Given("{actor}")
public void (Actor actor, io.cucumber.datatable.DataTable dataTable) {

}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Is project sample available?

Comment: Check also this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40212449/getting-scenario-and-steps-undefined-in-cucumber-with-java .

Answer (score 0):

I added glue then it works now.

```
todos.stepdefinitions net.serenitybdd.cucumber.actors
```